# Enable or Disable a Control without PostBack asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Greetings, I have an ASP.Net form with some standard controls (DropDownLists and TextBoxes) that I need to be disabled or enabled based on the checked state of a checkbox control.

I currently have it working via the CheckChanged event on a postback.
Can I use Ajax to accomplish the same thing without Posting Back?

Comment: In short:  yes. You have to ensure that the UpdatePanel around your enabled/disabled control(s) is updated afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery or Javascript to Hide or disable the controls client side.

Comment: Just remember to sanitise the input server side because users can modify the Javascript to enable/show the checkboxes.